# 2 way syncing Magento Open Source and Salesforce

Tags: third-party-module

Can this be done and how. Not finding any Connectors that sync both ways, just Magento to Salesforce. Do we need to create our own REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering whether you ever figured this out? As we also have the same question.